# Calculate time difference in python

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy

The datetime table field defined in postgresql:
 `Column("created_on",DateTime(timezone=True),default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)`,

In python code, I have converted current time to aware-time as:

```
mcurr_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

I get curr time as:

> 2017-03-30 21:44:51.394387+00:00

When I retrieve the time from the table using sqlalchemy I get:

> mcreation_time = 2017-03-30 15:05:01.350078+05:30

How to find difference between the 2 or what conversion has to be used
to compare the difference with hours? All the tables have timezone
aware datetime. I need the exact code as I checked all examples and am confused.

The difference in the 2 dates is valid without any conversion. The result has to be compared with example 2 hours(variable var1) and based on the output, certain actions need to be taken.  This 2 hours I have converted as:

```
mcalc = datetime.timedelta(seconds=var1*60*60)
```

So what I wish to do is,

```
diff_tm = (mcurr_time - mcreations_time)

if diff_tm > mcalc:
    do_some1()
else:
    do_some2()
```

I **do not know if any conversion is required in any of the dates,** preferably the current time as all my tables are defined as mentioned above.
The time difference in the 2 dates should be correct from any client i.e from any place in the world

Comment: subtraction of datetimes result in an datetime.timedelta object. `interval = mcurr_time - mcreation_time`. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by removing timezone offset and using in calculation:

```
mcurr_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
mcurr_time = mcurr_time.replace(
          tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None))

mcreation_time = mcreation_time.replace(
          tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None))
```